# How can I define an extension member on an F# unit of measure?

Tags: f#, extension-methods, units-of-measurement

Leaving aside whether we should use units of measure for unitless concepts like angles, suppose I have define `degree` and `radian` units in F#

```
type [<Measure>] degree =
    static member ToRadians (d:float<degree>) : float<radian> = d * (Math.PI * 1.<radian>) / 180.0<degree>
and [<Measure>] radian =
    static member ToDegrees (r:float<radian>) : float<degree> = r * 180.0<degree> / (Math.PI * 1.<radian>)
```

I can use them relatively easily like

```
4.0<degree> |> degree.ToRadians
```

It seems like extension members would be even handier. So I could just say

```
let d = 4.0<degree>
let r = d.ToRadians()
```

But I can't define the extension member the obvious way

```
type float<degree> with
    member degrees.ToRadians() = degree.ToRadians(degrees)
```

... this gets me the following error

```
error FS0010: Unexpected identifier in type name. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.
```

Is there a syntactic trick for extension members on units of measure in F#, or is the feature supported?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that it isn't supported. Everything I tried gave the error: `Measure declarations may have only static members`.

Comment: The problem is that the measure type information is removed after compiling, so at runtime everything is just a `float` so calling an instance method doesn't make sense

Comment: @jpalmer. During compilation extension members are resolved statically.

Comment: @Sebastion Good - exactly, once the type checks are done, the extra type information is removed and your code is just compiled to operations on standard `floats`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# extension members are different from C# extension members in that you can't define extensions of constructed generic types.  For instance, you can define extensions on `seq<'t>`, but not `seq<int>`.  In other words, extension members really act like members of the type, rather than static methods.  This applies to measure types too, so you can't define an extension on `float<degree>`, but you can define an extension on `float<[<Measure>]'u>`:

```
type float<[<Measure>]'u> with
    member f.Squared() = f * f

[<Measure>]
type m

let area = 2.0<m>.Squared()
```

However, I don't see how this helps you in your case...

Comment: That makes good sense. There's no real benefit from defining these extension methods other than syntax, and there's plenty of other good options.